# How to make button click from an static method in android

Tags: android, android-activity, click, static-methods, non-static

I have one Button "Submit", and i want to make 'submit.performclick' inside static method, i tried but i cant, help me to overcome this issue, and one more thing, inside that click action, there may be an any non static methods.. but i want to make button click.

```
 new_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CallingDataBase("fm Btn","from button");
            ClearMemory();
        }
    });
public void CallingDataBase(String mobileNumber, String mobileMessage)
{
        us = mobileNumber;
        pa = mobileMessage;
        insertion(us,pa);
        CallingCustomAdapter();
}

//this static method was the first calling method.
  public static void updateMessageBox(String mobileNum12, String mobileMessa12,Context context)
//I get parameters for this method from another class.
{   

//      SMS smsClass = new SMS();    // SMS was my Class Name`
//      smsClass.function(context);
//       from here i want to call button action   


}
```

Comment: Please paste your code which you have tried..

Comment: help me to over come this issue. i have pasted my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the static method a reference to your button as an argument, in the following manner :

```java
//this static method was the first calling method.
public static void updateMessageBox( Button button , String mobileNum12, String mobileMessa12,Context context)
//I get parameters for this method from another class.
{   

//      SMS smsClass = new SMS();    // SMS was my Class Name`
//      smsClass.function(context);
//       from here i want to call button action   
button.performClick();

}
```